How to navigate to the cell with the data I selected on a chart in Excel?
I create a (let's say `Scatter') chart from data and when I highlight the dot on a chart I can see the values. How can I now navigate to the source table exactly to the cell which contains this data?
I have many dots and need to work further with one specific value and every time I have to write the values and search for them in the table. Could this be done simpler?

At the beginning, you need to select a chart and one point on it. Then run a macro like this:
Sub SelectPointFromChart()
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Point" Then
        Dim ser As Long, pt As Long
        ser = Split(Split(Selection.Name, "S")(1), "P")(0)
        pt = Split(Split(Selection.Name, "S")(1), "P")(1)
        Dim sf As String, x As Range, y As Range
        sf = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(ser).Formula
        Set x = Range(Split(sf, ",")(1))
        Set y = Range(Split(sf, ",")(2))
        Union(x(pt), y(pt)).Select
    End If
End Sub

After the macro is executed, 2 cells with x and y values of the chart point will be selected.

Thank you, will check soon. So, are you saying with this, that there is no such build-in capability (feature) in Excel charts? Am I really the first person who needed this in Excel and people don't really use Excel to analyze data in this way? Just curious if all users use macro for this. The drawback that I will have to copy macro or data to the table, since I get actual data in CSV from another source. Anyway, thank you so much for the option!
